# Uncaught TypeError: chart.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I'm trying to pass the string value from my controller to my javascript to render my chart thru on click of a button.

In my controller I query the needed data and echo the return value, below is the value

```
 new CanvasJS.Chart("myChart", {
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    theme: "light2",
                    title:{
                        text: "Devices"
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        title: "From"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor:"pointer",
                         itemclick : toggleDataSeries
                    },
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true,
                        content: toolTipFormatter
                    },
                    data: [
                        {
                                type: "bar",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "A",
                                dataPoints: [{ y: 2, label: "Keyboard" },{ y: 13, label: "Laptop" }]},{
                                type: "bar",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "B",
                                dataPoints: [{ y: 1, label: "Keyboard" },{ y: 0, label: "Laptop" }]}
                    ]
                })
```

I used ajax to get the value above like below:

```
         var return_first = function () {
          var tmp = null;
          $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'type': "POST",
            'global': false,
            'dataType': 'html',
            'url': base_url + 'my_controller/dChart',
            'data': {
                'dev_fil' : $("#dev_fil").val()
            },
            'success': function (data) {
                tmp = data;
            }
        });
        return tmp;
    }();
```

And then I will assign it to a variable and `render()` it

```
 var chart = return_first;
 chart.render();
```

But it keeps on returning and error `Uncaught TypeError: chart.render is not a function`

I tried to just render it normally and not from ajax it displays the chart but I need to change the value of the chart when submitting a device name.

Thank you in advance for the help.

---UPDATE---

I tried to pass only the values inside the data[] and call the `render()` inside the success.

```
var return_first = function () {
          var tmp = null;
          $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'type': "POST",
            'global': false,
            'dataType': "html",
            'url': base_url + 'my_controller/dChart',
            'data': {
                'dev_fil' : $("#dev_fil").val()
            },
            'success': function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                tmp = new CanvasJS.Chart("myChart", {
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    theme: "light2",
                    title:{
                        text: "Device Replacement"
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        title: "Outlets"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor:"pointer",
                         itemclick : toggleDataSeries
                    },
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true,
                        content: toolTipFormatter
                    },
                    data: [data]
                });
                tmp.render();
            }
        });
        return tmp;
    }();
```

I'm having an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'name' in {
                                type: "bar",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "AA",
                                dataPoints: [{ y: 13, label: "Laptop" }]}
```

Its at canvas.minjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data comes through as a string, so you are assigning tmp to a string, which does not have the function render().  You need to eval() the string to have it execute the string as code, which would then create your object:

```
'success': function (data) {
            tmp = eval(data);
        }
```

Just a note, eval is generally not the best way to do things.  Here you might consider returning just the json settings in your API and creating the object in the success:

```
var return_first = function () {
      var tmp = null;
      $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'type': "POST",
        'global': false,
        'dataType': 'json', // notice we changed to 'json' here
        'url': base_url + 'my_controller/dChart',
        'data': {
            'dev_fil' : $("#dev_fil").val()
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            tmp = new CanvasJS.Chart("myChart", data);
        }
    });
    return tmp;
}();
```

--- UPDATE ---

Based on your most recent code, you want your server side to be returning this:

```
[
                        {
                                type: "bar",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "A",
                                dataPoints: [{ y: 2, label: "Keyboard" },{ y: 13, label: "Laptop" }]},{
                                type: "bar",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "B",
                                dataPoints: [{ y: 1, label: "Keyboard" },{ y: 0, label: "Laptop" }]}
                    ]
```

and your client-side code will look like this:

```
var return_first = function () {
          var tmp = null;
          $.ajax({
            'async': false,
            'type': "POST",
            'global': false,
            'dataType': "json", // note we set json here
            'url': base_url + 'my_controller/dChart',
            'data': {
                'dev_fil' : $("#dev_fil").val()
            },
            'success': function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                tmp = new CanvasJS.Chart("myChart", {
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    theme: "light2",
                    title:{
                        text: "Device Replacement"
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        title: "Outlets"
                    },
                    legend: {
                        cursor:"pointer",
                         itemclick : toggleDataSeries
                    },
                    toolTip: {
                        shared: true,
                        content: toolTipFormatter
                    },
                    data: data // notice data is not wrapped in brackets because it's already an array
                });
                tmp.render();
            }
        });
        return tmp;
    }();
```

Comment: I'm having an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: We remove the `dataType` and have an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'width' in`

Comment: Hello I tried to used eval() but I keep on having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

Comment: Hi, I read your update.  If you are returning the data array in your server function, you don't want to wrap data in the array.  It may be resolving to data: [[{...},{...}]].  In this case canvasjs is trying to iterate over an array with in, but it's expecting an object like this: data: [{...},{...}].  Maybe try to remove the [] from the data: wrapper, like so: data: [data] -> data: data

Comment: new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", JSON.parse(the json returnded by your server));

For me I had to add JSON.parse() as the example shows

Answer (score 0):

```
var chart = return_first;
chart.render();
```

return_first is your function that is making an ajax call, and you are assigning that to chart. So its normal that javascript is saying: hey, your return_first function doesnt have a function called render.

Maybe you need to assign to another variable your ChartJS var, and then call from there the render. Something like:

```
var myChart = new CanvasJS.Chart(...);
myChart.render();
```